# How to display a python-style dictionary with single backslashes in the value?

Tags: python, dictionary, escaping, character, backslash

I encounter a simple but weird question.
I want to display a dictionary like ***{‘file_path’: ‘\11.1.2.3\file1’}*** using following sentences:

```
>>> mydict = {'file_path': '\\\\11.1.2.3\\file1'}
>>> mydict
{'file_path': '\\\\11.1.2.3\\file1'}
```

I prepend ***r*** to the value string:

```
>>> mydict = {'file_path': r'\\11.1.2.3\file1'}
>>> mydict
{'file_path': '\\\\11.1.2.3\\file1'}
```

The result is same with the foregoing one, which are not expected.

Anyone can provide a method to **display the dictionary, not print the value only**? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make your own print function:

```
mydict = {'file_path1': r'\\11.1.2.3\file1', 'file_path2': r'\\111232.3\blabla'}
pairs = []
for k,v in mydict.items():
    pairs.append("'%s': '%s'" % (k,v))
print '{' + ', '.join(pairs) + '}'
```

Or if you only want one particular key.

```
mydict = {'file_path1': r'\\11.1.2.3\file1', 'file_path2': r'\\111232.3\blabla'}
pairs = []
for k,v in mydict.items():
    if k == 'file_path1':
        pairs.append("'%s': '%s'" % (k,v))
print '{' + ', '.join(pairs) + '}'
```

Using comprehension:

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to convert escaped characters.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> mydict = {'file_path': '\\\\11.1.2.3\\file1'}
>>> print(codecs.getdecoder("unicode_escape")(str(mydict))[0])
{'file_path': '\\11.1.2.3\file1'}
```

Comment: This method is suited to print the dictionary with only one key. It's not effective for printing one key in the dictionary with several keys.